# Use Something like Rails Generator for PHP Development

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake, generator

I want to create a command line based tool for PHP Development.

It should do something quite similar based on what the rails generator does as well as integrate with rake, as the rake tasks for the DB should also be available.

Or is there a ruby framework that allows to build such generators?

Comment: Write your own scripts and run them, perhaps? No need to bring Ruby tools like rake into this…

Answer (score 0):

Look into a few ORM projects like Doctrine, you can also look into some other frameworks like Symphony or Cake, I don't think there is one for Zend.

Answer (score 0):

Zend Framework has the API for building CLI tools on top of Zend_Tool. Besides, it has Zend_CodeGenerator component for most of PHP code reflection, extending and modifying. Writing own Zend_Tool providers is hard, but possible.
For ORM generation you should use Doctrine.

Answer (score 0):

If you want Rails-like functionality for PHP Development, why not use a similar framework? [CodeIgniter](http://codeigniter.com/), for example, has [database migrations](http://codeigniter.com/wiki/Migrations/) and [CakePHP](http://cakephp.org/) has [scaffolding](http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/The-Manual/Developing-with-CakePHP/Scaffolding.html) as well as migrations.